# Unity / CSharp: Wait for navMeshAgent to arrive with Async or something i don't know

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so i've been trying to make a function on characters (multiple) in Unity that wait for the character to arrive at a building with a `while()` loop, but it has not been easy goings...

So... this is what i got:

```
 public async void ExecuteTask(string task)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{this.FullName} is doing {task}");
        switch (task)
        {
            case "Sleep":
                if (this.CurrentLocation != this.Home.name) await GoTo(Home);
                break;
            case "Home":
                if (this.CurrentLocation != this.Home.name) await GoTo(Home);
                break;
            case "Work":
                if (this.CurrentLocation != this.Work.name) await GoTo(Work);
                break;
            default:
                Debug.LogWarning($"Pawn.cs > {this.FullName} caught out of bound task: {task}");
                break;
        }
    }

    private Task GoTo(GameObject building)
    {
        this.CurrentLocation = "World";
        Debug.Log($"Pawn.cs > {this.FullName}: Going to {building.name}");
        Vector3 target = building.GetComponent<Building>().EntryNode.transform.position;
        NavMeshAgent agent = this.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.destination = target;
        while (agent.hasPath) ;
        Debug.Log($"Pawn.cs > {this.FullName} has arrived at {building.name}");
        this.CurrentLocation = building.name;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

It's pretty straight forward, it gets a task every hour which i give to `ExecuteTask()`, sadly Unity crashes when i run this code, prob the `while()` loop, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong? Am i implementing tasks wrong? Can i not use it like this? Why? How do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`while(agent.hasPath);` is equivalent to the below, so it will be some infinite loop.

Please get rid of this code.

```
while(true)
{

}
```

Comment: but... 
when i set ```agent.destination = target``` the agent starts moving, i want the function to resume when it has arrived at the target, doesn't it become ```false``` then? and not infinite? or not?

Comment: @Riptide00 no, it’s always true. You can put a breakpoint and try to debug